# Is entityManager provider supposed to be created in guice or is it readily available?

Tags: jpa, guice

I was looking at this code and i was left with the impression that you do not have to  mplement a Provider. You can use it directly.How accurate is this?
EDIT: This code: https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/caarlos0/dao/GenericDao.java
EDIT2: Aha, so according to this : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html , providers are implemented by the injector ( Guice i understand and not the user of Guice). Great!. Can somebody please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are automatically created by Guice. The ones provided by Guice will obey the scope you have declared the target to be in.

If you need additional logic to be executed prior to the creation of an object that you will need to write a Provider, but this is quite rare.